# Removing elements from a 'full' array

Tags: java, arrays, element

This is a little assignment I am working on. I am a beginner Java programmer and have ran into an issue during this little program. For some reason, if the array contains 10 elements, the removal method does not work. I would love some advice/help in regards to fixing this issue.

When the array contains 10 elements, and I attempt to remove one, the arrangement of the elements in the textArea is not what it should be. Everything should shift over 1, containing 9 elements, with the last element as 0. When an element is removed, all the elements should adjust themselves and shift to the left.

The default appearance of the output is: **[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]**

If I enter the numbers 1 - 10, the output should look like this:
**[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]**

If the user attempts remove the last element, it will set it to 0:
**[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]**

However, if the user attempts to remove another element, lets say 5, the program throws an out of bounds exception in the console. If they remove 5, the output should be: **[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0]**

For more context, here are the assignment details:

> Create a complete program that has the ability to store and display integer values in an array. The maximum number of values that your program should be able to handle is 10.
>
> - Add additional elements to the array using screen input (textbox and button).
> - Remove array elements based on screen input (textbox and button).
> - List all of the elements in the array and compute the sum of all the elements.
> - List the even elements in the array and compute the sum of the even elements.
> - List the odd elements in the array and compute the sum of the odd elements.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class SumElement implements ActionListener {

    public static JButton add, remove, sumAll, sumEven, sumOdd;
    public static JTextField inputField;
    public static JTextArea textArea;
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static int[] numbers = new int[10];
    public static JLabel titleText;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);

        // Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Integer Sums");
        frame.setSize(178, 240);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Container panel
        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        frame.setContentPane(container);

        // Title panel
        JPanel titlePane = new JPanel();
        titleText = new JLabel("Integer Sums");

        // Content panel
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 180));
        content.setLayout(null);

        // Buttons
        add = new JButton("Add");
        add.setBounds(4, 50, 80, 20);
        add.addActionListener(new SumElement());

        remove = new JButton("Remove");
        remove.setBounds(88, 50, 80, 20);
        remove.addActionListener(new SumElement());

        sumAll = new JButton("Sum All");
        sumAll.setBounds(4, 74, 164, 20);
        sumAll.addActionListener(new SumElement());

        sumEven = new JButton("Sum Even");
        sumEven.setBounds(4, 98, 164, 20);
        sumEven.addActionListener(new SumElement());

        sumOdd = new JButton("Sum Odd");
        sumOdd.setBounds(4, 122, 164, 20);
        sumOdd.addActionListener(new SumElement());

        // Text area, and text field
        inputField = new JTextField();
        inputField.setBounds(4, 21, 164, 25);

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Input integer value below:");
        inputLabel.setBounds(12, 6, 164, 13);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setBounds(4, 144, 165, 36);

        // Adding everything
        container.add(titlePane);
        titlePane.add(titleText);
        container.add(content);
        content.add(inputLabel);
        content.add(inputField);
        content.add(scrollPane);
        content.add(add);
        content.add(remove);
        content.add(sumAll);
        content.add(sumEven);
        content.add(sumOdd);

        // Extras
        frame.toFront();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
            if (counter == 10) {
                titleText.setText("Error: too many values");
            } else {
                numbers[counter] = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
                textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()) == numbers[i]) {
                    for (int x = i; x < counter - 1; x++) {
                        numbers[x] = numbers[x + 1];
                    }
                    textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
                    counter--;
                } else {
                    titleText.setText("Error: value doesn't exist");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum All")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum is " + sum);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum Even")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum of even values is: " + sum);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum Odd")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum of odd values is: " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the modified actionPerformed portion of the code. Removing the last array value now works. However, if the array is full, and the user attempts to remove an element other than the last one, an error is thrown. I am still unsure how to fix this error.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Add")) {
            if (counter == 10) {
                titleText.setText("Error: too many values");
            } else {
                numbers[counter] = Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText());
                textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()) == numbers[9]) {
                numbers[9] = 0;
                counter--;
                textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()) == numbers[i]) {
                        for (int x = i; x <= counter - 1; x++) {
                            numbers[x] = numbers[x + 1];
                        }
                        textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
                        counter--;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum All")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum is " + sum);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum Even")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum of even values is: " + sum);
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Sum Odd")) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    sum += numbers[i];
                }
            }
            titleText.setText("Sum of odd values is: " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the counter - 1 in the for loop of remove element is the problem. It should be x <= counter. The moving of next value to current value should be conditional I.e. if 10th element is removed, just assign 0 to the 10th element rather than moving the next element to current.

Comment: Please be more specific about what 'it does not work mean'. The best thing you can do is provide a `1: set of inputs` (what's in your array, e.g. 10,9,...,1), `2: what you do to it` (e.g. "I try to remove number 3"), `3: expected result` (e.g. I expect array to be ....), `4: actual result`

Comment: Edited question with specifics.

Comment: @jzbakos you're not being specific enough - you've shown the homework question, and your code, but you've not described what you think *should* be happening and what you *actually* see happening. "the arrangement of the elements in the textArea is not what it should be. Everything should shift over 1, containing 9 elements, with the last element as 0." when the way you show the content is with `Array.toString(numbers)` is a description that doesn't make sense.

Comment: It seems to me that your remove code does the right thing to the array and counter, only it erroneously prints “Error: value doesn't exist” for each element in the array that differs from the entered value — could it be so?

Comment: Okay, so I added a bit more info and a slight fix. The code now does everything it should except one thing. If there are 10 elements in the array, and the user attempts to remove an element other than the last one, it throws an error in the console. Unsure of how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should remove the integer value correctly if exists. However, it doesn't handle the scenario where multiple values of same integer in the array exists (i.e. array has 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0 and try to remove 1) . It doesn't remove all 1s and show all 0s in the text box.

I am not sure whether the requirement is to have unique values in the array. If that is the case, the add function should be changed to handle the scenario.

```
else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Remove")) {
            boolean removed = false;
            titleText.setText("Integer Sums");
            for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()) == numbers[i]) {
                    for (int x = i; x < counter; x++) {
                        if (x == 9) {
                            numbers[x] = 0;
                        } else {
                            numbers[x] = numbers[x + 1];
                            numbers[x + 1] =0;
                        }
                    }
                    textArea.setText(Arrays.toString(numbers));
                    counter--;
                    removed = true;
                }               
            }
            if (!removed) {
                titleText.setText("Error: value doesn't exist");
            } 
            System.out.println("Counter: " + counter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem should be in this liens of code:

```
for (int x = i; x <= counter - 1; x++) {
    numbers[x] = numbers[x + 1];
}
```

Then the array Contains 10 elements the variable counter is 10. 
In this case the iteration will work to counter -1 which is 9. In the next line you try to get “numbers[x + 1]” which is 10[(x=9)+1] and so gets an out of bounds. 
If you change it to counter -2 instead of -1 it should work, since atm you get the element from the next field to fill the place it should still work.

Comment: When I try that, the program no longer works. If the output was: [1, 2, 3] and i removed 2, it changed to [1, 3, 3] instead of what it is supposed to be: [1, 3, 0].

Comment: @jzbakos those example numbers are what all people will find really helpful to answer your question

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Check the post now.